# facebook like html lightbox

Tags: javascript, plugins

I am looking for a lightbox like effect script.

When click on a link or button, it will load the html/php file with the lightbox effect on the same page.

I know there are many such script available, but these scripts will have the pop-up form disappear whenever I click on the outer surroundings of the pop-up form. Is there any scripts that can have those pop-up forms remain when clicked on the outer section just like the ones on facebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colorbox would be my lightbox of choice: http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/, although @julesanchez suggestion of shadowbox is an excellent choice as well.

Comment: nice. how do I make it where the box does not disappear when clicked on the side? I wan to close it only by clicking on the 'close' button on the popup box

Comment: you use the option overlayClose:false when creating i.e.: $(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1',overlayClose:false});

Comment: The close button is automatically provided.  overlayClose:false tells it to not close UNLESS you click the (X) button

Answer (score 1):

Try the shadowbox script, you can download it at : http://www.shadowbox-js.com/

Comment: nice. how do I make it where the box does not disappear when clicked on the side? I wan to close it only by clicking on the 'close' button on the popup box

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what you're looking for: http://davidwalsh.name/dw-content/lightface.php

Comment: Hi, where do i download the script